# Mongoose count elements in array by username and type

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a collection `Guilds`. In `Guilds` I have array property:

```
    "latestActivity" : [ 
        {
            "username" : "Zlotte",
            "img" : "necromancer.png",
            "borrowGold" : true,
            "amount" : "3",
            "createdAt" : "2019-08-23"
        }, 
        {
            "username" : "Zlotte",
            "img" : "necromancer.png",
            "borrowGold" : true,
            "amount" : "3",
            "createdAt" : "2019-08-23"
        },
]
```

now I need to count all these latest activities by `username` and `borrowGold`. How do I do that ? This is my current function:

```
    const borrowedToday = await Guild.find({
                            "members.username": user.username,
                            "latestActivity.username": user.username, 
                            "latestActivity.borrowGold": true,
                            "latestActivity.createdAt": todayDate
                        }).count();
    console.log(borrowedToday);
```

But this returns me `1` probably because it count's the found `guild` itself not the `latestActivities`.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to count the amount of gold borrowed, or the number of times they have borrowed gold that day?

Comment: @CorrieMacDonald The amount of times the user has borrowed the gold that day

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to aggregate this to get an efficient and reliable result. 
You should include an elimination `$match` stage, and then a `$project` stage to get the size of subdocuments that match a set of given filter criteria. For example:

```
const result = await Guild.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    "members.username": user.username,
    "latestActivity.username": user.username, 
    "latestActivity.borrowGold": true,
    "latestActivity.createdAt": todayDate
  }},
  {
    $project: {
        "timesBorrowed": {
            "$size": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$latestActivity",
                    "as": "items",
                    "cond": { 
                        "$and": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$$items.borrowGold", true ] },
                            { "$eq": [ "$$items.createdAt", todayDate ] }
                        ] 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);

if (result) {
  const timesBorrowed = result[0].timesBorrowed;
  console.log(timesBorrowed);
} else console.error('Error.')
```

**EDIT**

I tested this out locally with the supplied data and I'm successfully getting the number of times a particular user has borrowed gold that day. You could easily amend the aggregate pipeline to also extract the total amount borrowed too.